# Unable to start MongoDB MMS agent

Tags: mongodb-mms

I installed the MMS agent for CentOS and when I start it as a service I see the following error in the log file , I have searched for this error , but could not find any reference can someone let me know what the issue is .

```
/usr/bin/mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent: error while loading shared libraries: libsasl2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thank You.

Comment: The same problem occurs on Fedora 20

Comment: The same problem on my cent os anyone find solution?

Comment: scroll down to @jmdiego solution

Answer (score 9):

I wrote to mongdb support and after their response, I was able to start the agent, the response was this:

> To the best of my knowledge, Fedora 20 is equivalent to RHEL 7 which
>   is not yet supported by MongoDB.  There is work planned for this
>   latter OS, but I cannot guarantee a timetable for that release.  In
>   the meantime, I believe it is possible to work around the issue with
>   the following:
>
> > cd /lib64
> >
> > sudo ln -s libsasl2.so.3.0.0 libsasl2.so.2
>
> Hopefully this helps, and allows you to start the agent.

Thanks to André de Frere from MongoDB.

Comment: this is the real answer

Comment: I had a similar problem and `sudo ln -s libsasl2.so.3.0.0 libsasl2.so.2` was the solution

Answer (score 3):

Solution for the above problem is mongo db uses snmp package for network communication across the installation of standalone, replication & sharding environment

We need to add 7 packages that are dependencies for snmp.

Copy the respective files from another system and move all the packages to /usr/lib64 & /usr/lib/

Let say we need package libsasl2.so.2.0.0

ln -s /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2

u have to do for all the dependencies required.

Answer (score 0):

The missing library is provider by the cyrus-sasl-lib rpm.

you should download and install it from the link below ;)

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/libsasl2.so.2()(64bit)

let me know if this solve your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I expierenced same issue, because of my fault

I downloaded incorrect RPM version for my RedHat. Mongo provides agent download for

- RHEL/CentOS (7.X)
- RHEL/CentOS (5.X, 6.X)

I installed for 7th where my RedHat was 6.7
Check your version 
cat /etc/redhat-release

If you installed incorrect version then uninstall package
sudo rpm -e mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent

And install again correct one